# Black screen after boot

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup

I am unable to boot my Late 2015 MacBook Pro. After the chime sound, I can see that the backlight comes on, but there is no image. Same thing happens when I plug in an external display - there is nothing on either screen, even with closed lid. The other boot options - safe mode, recovery mode, verbose mode, target disk mode or diagnostics do nothing. NVRAM reset, plays the chime sound and we are back to the black screen.

This is the result of all the actions I have tried to salvage data on the drive. Here is what I did beforehand:

- I was typing in Webstorm when I got the black screen - computer restarted because of a problem
- after restart, it booted to the question mark screen
- then I booted in to recovery mode
- first aid reported that - "Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting"
- I could not create an image of the internal disk, it always ended with an error (-61, 3 and then 5)
- next I tried to reinstall os, but the screen where you choose the disk as installation location was empty
- next I have tried to use `diskutil` in terminal - but it did not find any `logical CoreStorage volume` and when I tried to use `diskutil` with `mountDisk` it did not appear in volumes
- after a few restarts it refused to boot in any mode
- I tried to reset NVRAM and SCM
- then I managed to boot to recovery mode **that looked like an older version**, but this time `diskutil` showed **only** recovery partition and nothing else
- after next restart it again refused to boot in any mode
- then I tried to boot from USB with El Capitan, which I managed to do after few attempts
- installation also did not see any disk, so I have plugged in an external drive and installed the os there
- after the installation, I could use the laptop - however I was unable to find or mount the internal storage
- then I tried to restart again and got back to the black screen, but this time I can not even boot from the external disk or the bootable USB - every attempt or combination to boot ends with the black screen

To me it looks like the internal disk is completely gone and I wont be able to salvage anything from it.

Is there something else I can do?

Comment: My iMac suffered similar symptoms recently due to a failure of the SSD component of my "Fusion Drive". I found `Disk Utility` to be completely worthless for troubleshooting, but [DriveDx](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) immediately diagnosed the problem. Re "something else": Without a backup, I can't think of anything useful, but you might check with [beetstech](https://beetstech.com/); I've used them & they seem competent.